# How does UDF in MySQL work internally and the reason behind the time difference between the two methods available

Tags: mysql

There are two ways in creating an UDF

a) By using a CREATE FUNCTION syntax which directly creates a function in that particular database.
Eg:

http://www.sqlexamples.info/PHP/mysql_udf1.htm

b) By writing a C code, compiling it and using its .so library file and linking it to the mysql server and then creating a function in mysql

Eg:

http://blog.loftdigital.com/blog/how-to-write-mysql-functions-in-c

In the first method (a),

```
CREATE FUNCTION `func`(variable INT) RETURNS int(11)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
RETURN variable
END
```

it takes about **12** seconds to return the data for a select query like

```
select fiscal(col1) from table;
```

where

```
select col1 from table;
```

takes only about **0.42** seconds!!

where as the same written in C code takes only around **0.64** seconds!

I wanted to know what is that that is causing this time difference for a simple return function with no processing done in it. Also wanted to know how mySql allocates memory to these two different methods.